# Apply a volumetric texture tangentially on a torus

Tags: texturing, coordinates, volumetrics

I'm trying to adjust a volumetric texture on a torus object.

Some details on this object:

- The material is a volume whose density is driven by a texture.
- This texture is a procedural one such as marble/musgrave.
- This texture is mapped on the object (the torus) with a tube projection.

My problem is that I whish to position and stretch this texture **tangentially** around the torus and I didn't manage to get this result. I tried many settings and I didn't succeed.

Here are some results I obtained :

[image]
[image]

And nearly what I would like :

[image]

I thought that in a tube projection, the **y coordinate** was the **angle of rotation** but I think I didn't undertand how Blender projection system is working.

I also tried to change the projection system to **sphere** and the mapping coordinates to **global** but it didn't work

[image]

My questions are :

- Have you ever succed to apply a texture **tangentially** (or **radially**) on any object ?
- Do you have some hints/explanations on the blender projection system (especially tube and spheric projection) ?
- Do you know other ways to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get a radial result:

[image]

The key is to use a 'Blend' type texture (instead of marble) as this has the option to do radial mapping:

[image]

I use a custom ramp for the black and white bars (set to 'constant' blending), a radial blend and default mapping settings.

One other setting which has to be enabled is 'RGB to intensity':

[image]

I use the default volume settings for the material, apart from 'Density' which is 0.

Comment: Make exactly what I want ... Great !